# check if all fields are null in a model c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, webapi

I have the model below. in future the number for field may increase. i would like to know how I can possibly check that all fields for a model are null. in .net core c#

```
public class model
{
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? TimeZoneOffset { get; set; }
    public TimeOnly? RolloverTime { get; set; }
    public bool? IncludeCurrent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Write a method (returning a `bool`) that checks all property values for `null`. If you wanted a more general solution, you could write a generic method (in `<T>`) that reflects over all the readable properties of `T`, and then tests all reference type (or nullable value type) property values for null-ness. However, unless you have a lot of them, just writing an `AreAllPropertiesNull` method is probably better. If you are going to be doing this a lot, it might be worth creating a `TestForNullProperties<T>` class that stores all the property Getters, and then lazily cache them by typeof `T`

Comment: ^^ this. Plus: you could also consider source generation to avoid runtime reflection or 3rd party libs like Fluent Validation.

Comment: If you don't want properties to be able to be null, use non-nullable reference types.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the three choices I presented as a comment.

**First**: *Create a method on your model class to do the work.*

This is the simplest way (certainly, the simplest to think about).  The downside is that it requires work on each model class, and more importantly, can be a pain to maintain (since every update to your model requires an update to the method.

One thing to note, it will necessarily always be the fastest to execute.

Like @RolanShun, I chose to create an interface to describe models that follow this behavior (it's not worth wasting the model's one possible base class on this since there is no common behavior between implementations)

The interface:

```
public interface INullPropertiesCheckable
{
    bool AreAllPropertiesNull();
}
```

and an implementation:

```cs
public class MyModel : INullPropertiesCheckable
{
    public string? Duration { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? TimeZoneOffset { get; set; }
    public TimeOnly? RolloverTime { get; set; }
    public bool? IncludeCurrent { get; set; }

    public bool AreAllPropertiesNull()
    {
        return
            (Duration == null &&
             !TimeZoneOffset.HasValue &&
             !RolloverTime.HasValue &&
             !IncludeCurrent.HasValue);
    }
}
```

**Second:** *Use straight-up Reflection*

This will be the slowest to execute (since you are reflecting over the type, fetching the property getters and invoking them on each call).  However, it's easy to understand, easy to write, and it requires no per-model coding:

```
public static bool CheckAllPropertiesAreNull<T>(T obj) 
{
    var readableProps = typeof(T).GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public).Where(p => p.CanRead);
    foreach (var prop in readableProps)
    {
        if (prop.GetValue(obj) != null)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Third:** *Use Reflection, but create and cache reflection workers*

If you are going to do this a lot, and call the method often, this may be the way to go.  It does the Reflection heavy lifting (reflecting over the type and discovering the property getters) once per type, and caches the results.  Each call just pulls up the correct worker (from a dictionary keyed on the type), and quickly invokes all the property getters.

I use this pattern fairly frequently.

```
public class ArePropsNullWorker
{
    // access to the (static) cached ArePropsNullWorker instances
    private static Dictionary<Type, ArePropsNullWorker> workerCache = new Dictionary<Type, ArePropsNullWorker>();
    private static object workerLock = new object();

    // The List and the constructor are private, and are per-instance
    private List<MethodInfo> propertyReaders = new List<MethodInfo>();

    private ArePropsNullWorker(Type type)
    {
        var readableProps = type.GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public).Where(p => p.CanRead);
        foreach (var prop in readableProps)
        {
            var propertyReader = prop.GetGetMethod();
            if (propertyReader != null)     //should never be null, but the compiler doesn't know that
            {
                propertyReaders.Add(propertyReader);
            }
        }
    }

    public static bool CheckAllPropertiesAreNull<T>(T obj)
    {
        ArePropsNullWorker? worker;
        lock (workerLock)
        {
            if (!workerCache.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out worker))
            {
                worker = new ArePropsNullWorker(typeof(T));
                workerCache.Add(typeof(T), worker);
            }
            // at this point, worker will point to a valid, non-null ArePropsNullWorker
        }
        foreach (var propertyReader in worker.propertyReaders)
        {
            object? propertyValue = propertyReader.Invoke(obj, null);
            if (propertyValue != null)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

Looking at the code, you can see that access to this is provided by the static `ArePropsNullWorker.CheckAllPropertiesAreNull<T>(T obj)`.

Access to the only instance constructor for the class is `private`, all instances are managed within the static members of the class.  Since I'm guessing you intend to use this in a web app, I added a `lock` to allow multi-threaded access.

Answer (score 0):

You can either write an extension method or some helper method to check if any field is NULL and return the Boolean flag.

```
void Main()
{
        var m = new model() { Duration = "abc", IncludeCurrent = true};
         CheckIfAnyPropertyNull(m).Dump();
}

public static bool CheckIfAnyPropertyNull(model m)
{
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(model).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            if(property.GetValue(m) == null)
                return true;
        }
        
        return false;
}

public class model
{
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? TimeZoneOffset { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? RolloverTime { get; set; }
    public bool? IncludeCurrent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And for `CheckIfAnyPropertyNull`, replace `== null` by `!= null` and reverse `true` and `false`.

Comment: @CompuChip, we can't do that as it may result wrong results. Imagine there are 2 properties in the model with first property as not null and second being null - in this case, the function would return false which is wrong as second property is still NULL.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Implement interface on any class that need this null check
public interface iVerifyNull
{
    bool CheckIfAnyPropertyNull();
}

public class model: iVerifyNull
{
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? TimeZoneOffset { get; set; }
    public TimeOnly? RolloverTime { get; set; }
    public bool? IncludeCurrent { get; set; }

    public bool CheckIfAnyPropertyNull()
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(model).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            if (property.GetValue(this) == null)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}

//Usage
model model1 = new model(){ Duration = "abc", IncludeCurrent = null};;
if (model1.CheckIfAnyPropertyNull())
{
     //Null value found, do what you need to do here...
}
```

Comment: You are better off using an abstract class i think, instead of an interface. So you arent defining the same method in each class. (as its quite generic). The OP also asked for if ALL properties are null, rather than ANY. but the concept is there, and easy to modify.

Comment: An interface is more appropriate. There is no standard method implementation to use, and by using an interface, you allow the model class to inherit from a base _entity_ class if that's desirable